# Magento 2 set cookie on a phtml file

Tags: magento2, cookie

Can anyone please tell me how to set and get cookie on a phtml file in magento 2?? I don't want to create or use any extension for this.

Answer (score 8):

Try it.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cookieManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface');

// set cookie value
$cookieManager->setPublicCookie('custome1', 'custome1');

//get cookie value
$cookieManager->getCookie('custome1');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But this not worked.

Comment: refresh 2 times your page.

Answer (score 5):

Magento 2 cookie will not work when cache is enabled.
You have to make your phtml file uncacheable.

Use **cacheable="false"** property in your xml.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.file" template="Vendor_Module::custom.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
```

Now You can use cookie manager in your phtml file.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cookieManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface');

// Set cookie
$cookieManager->setPublicCookie('cookiename', 'cookievalue');

// Get cookie
$cookieManager->getCookie('cookiename');

// Delete cookie
$cookieManager->deleteCookie('cookiename');
```